# Uncaught TypeError in JS when trying to use .split()

Tags: javascript, split

Why I keep getting the

> "Uncaught TypeError: segEnDia.split is not a function"

in this example that I want to make it work?

```
var cantidadDada = 1000;
var segEnDia = cantidadDada / 86400;
var segEnDiaSplit = segEnDia.split(".");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`segEnDia` is not a string but a number. You have to convert the value to a string. Try this:

```
var cantidadDada = 1000;
var segEnDia = cantidadDada / 86400;
var segEnDiaSplit = ("" + segEnDia).split(".");
```

Comment: Probably more semantic to use toString: `segEnDia.toString().split(".");`

Comment: Yes, I've used .toString(), thanks! But the thing that I haven't see was that I needed to convert the result into a string.